# iOS offline HLS file size

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, http-live-streaming, avasset

In iOS 10, Apple added offline HLS.  In the documentation, they mention:

> Important: Downloaded HLS assets are stored on disk in a private
>   bundle format. This bundle format may change over time, and developers
>   should not attempt to access or store files within the bundle
>   directly, but should instead use AVFoundation and other iOS APIs to
>   interact with downloaded assets.

It appears the access to information about these files is limited.  I'm trying to find the size of the stored file.  Here is what I do.  After download finishes, I save the relative path

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        //Save path
        video?.downloadPath = location.relativePath

    }
```

later I reconstruct the file path as follows

```
if let assetPath = workout.downloadPath {
                let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())
                let assetURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(assetPath)
```

This works:

```
try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: assetURL)
```

This does not and returns an error that the file doesn't exist:

```
let att = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: assetURL.absoluteString)
```

I can load in the video asset as follows and play it offline with:

```
let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: assetURL)
```

But this returns me an empty array:

```
let tracks = avAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
```

Once again I'm just trying to get the file size of an offline HLS asset.  It appears the other answers on SO for getting a file size using FileManager don't work for these nor do the answers for getting the size of a loaded AVAsset.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

## Swift 5.3 Solution

Here is how to calculate offline HLS (.movpkg) File Size:

```
/// Calculates HLS File Size.
/// - Parameter directoryPath: file directory path.
/// - Returns: Human Redable File Size.
func getHLSFileSize(at directoryPath: String) -> String? {
    var result: String? = nil
    let properties: [URLResourceKey] = [.isRegularFileKey,
                                        .totalFileAllocatedSizeKey,
                                        /*.fileAllocatedSizeKey*/]

    guard let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: directoryPath),
                                         includingPropertiesForKeys: properties,
                                         options: .skipsHiddenFiles,
                                         errorHandler: nil) else {

                                            return nil
    }

    let urls: [URL] = enumerator
        .compactMap { $0 as? URL }
        .filter { $0.absoluteString.contains(".frag") }

    let regularFileResources: [URLResourceValues] = urls
        .compactMap { try? $0.resourceValues(forKeys: Set(properties)) }
        .filter { $0.isRegularFile == true }

    let sizes: [Int64] = regularFileResources
        .compactMap { $0.totalFileAllocatedSize! /* ?? $0.fileAllocatedSize */ }
        .compactMap { Int64($0) }

    
    let size = sizes.reduce(0, +)
    result = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(size), countStyle: .file)
    
    return result
}
```

### Usage

```
if let url = URL(string: localFileLocation),
    let size = self.getHLSFileSize(at: url.path) {
    result = String(size)
}
```

Comment: Neat & clean 

Comment: For me the code above didn't work. Investigated some time and made it work. I changed initialisation of FileManager, from fileURLWithPath to simple URL() -> FileManager.default.enumerator(at: directoryPath, ... where directoryPath is URL, also removed compactMap for url, changed it to simple for loop `var urls: [URL] = []
        
        for element in enumerator {
            if let url = element as? URL, url.absoluteString.contains(".frag") {
                urls.append(url)
            }
        }` And it worked

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to sum all files sizes inside a folder where your downloaded content is stored.

```
- (NSUInteger)hlsFileSize:(NSURL *)fileURL {

    NSUInteger size = 0;

    let enumerator = [NSFileManager.defaultManager enumeratorAtURL:fileURL includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:0 errorHandler:nil];
    for (NSURL *url in enumerator) {
        NSError *error = nil;

        // Get values
        let resourceValues = [url resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLIsRegularFileKey, NSURLFileAllocatedSizeKey, NSURLNameKey] error:&error];

        // Skip unregular files
        let isRegularFile = [resourceValues[NSURLIsRegularFileKey] boolValue];
        if (!isRegularFile) {
            continue;
        }

        let fileAllocatedSize = [resourceValues[NSURLFileAllocatedSizeKey] unsignedLongLongValue];

        size += fileAllocatedSize;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
let att = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: assetURL.path)
```

Comment: Hey, so I actually get attributes now however, the file size seems totally wrong.  I downloaded two files and they both return 204 for "let fileSize = attr[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64"  First neither of them should be that small and they are both very different sizes.

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: I used to have the same problem which is why I (in general) use the function from this gist to get proper filesize estimations: https://gist.github.com/blender/a75f589e6bd86aa2121618155cbdf827 When using the `allocatedSizeOfDirectory(at:)` with your assetURL it should work. I got 1435750400 Bytes which is exactly what the phone's storage estimates for this asset (1.44Gb)